# Change the background image and making it stay on every page

Tags: javascript

I have created a site where the user can change the image of a page from 4 available imges(which works fine), but when you go to another page, the image changes back to the default.

I'm new at Javascript and trying to create an if else statement but I can't seem to get it to work.

This is something I am after:

```
if (currentpage == body.style.backgroundImage="url('image1.png')")
 {
   allotherpages == body.style.backgroundImage="url('image1.png')";
 }
else if (currentpage == body.style.backgroundImage="url('image2.png')")
 {
   allotherpages == body.style.backgroundImage="url('image2.png')";
 }
```

I would appreciate any help or a point in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: you can look into using cookies or using AJAX to update user profile in database (if applicable)

Answer (score 0):

You want to save the current user's background when he changes page?

Use cookies to save the current background or store it in a database

Comment: Yes, there are 4 background coloured images, red, orange, blue, pink, (default is grey) and when the user selects red in the current page it works fine and the colour changes, but when they click on link 2 for example, it goes back to the default grey image which it what I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the background
2. Save it
3. When you change page, load the saved background

Save the background name in cookie for exemple:

```
$.cookie("currentBackground", "image1.png");
```

When you load your page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var currentBackground = $.cookie("currentBackground");
});
```